# Adding result of two values in html

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a "project calculator" in HTML/javascript for the consultancy business I work in. I need it to show the price of a consultant based on the consultant's title rank. I did this with the select tag and p tag (for showing the price).

I have also added an input box, where number of hours should be filled in. Thereby I need to add the price of the consultant (from the p tag) with the number of hours - this number needs to be shown somewhere on the HTML page.

I found out that I cannot calculate with p values - but I don't know how else I can make this calculation. Maybe there is another solution to displaying the consultant price than the p tag?

```html
<select style="position:absolute; left: 20%;" id = "title1">
    <option value = "Consultant">Consultant</option>
    <option value = "Senior Consultant">Senior Consultant</option>
    <option value = "Principal">Principal</option>
    <option value = "Expert Director">Expert Director</option>
    <option value = "Partner">Partner</option>
        </select>
<button onclick="price1()">Calculate price</button>
<p id="pr1"></p>    
<input type="number" id="hours1" placeholder="Number of hours on the project">
```

Comment: Can you show your JS code too?

Comment: Can we see the Javascript? It probably matters more.

Comment: "I found out that I cannot calculate with p values"...what do you mean exactly? Assuming the price is the only thing inside the p tag, then just grab the innerText of the tag, parse it as a number, and then use it in your calculation

Comment: Or as an alternative, if you prefer, you could display the consultant price inside a read-only text box. But it doesn't make much practical difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse an integer from the value of a p tag and make you calculations with that int.

```
var price = parseInt(document.getElementById("pr1").innerText, 10);
```

In case you need to calculate also the price for half hours you may parse a float.

Kind Regards

Ruben Kober